# How to prevent delimeter being the part of input when use `read.csv`?

Tags: r, ascii, delimiter, read.csv

I have csv file as below:

```
id,age,note
241,18,I am handsome,I am 18.
242,19, <ul>
    <li>
        <strong>I like music</strong><br />
        Talor swift：I kike Talor,I like her concert{smile}.<br />
        Beyonce:I have 3 albums.</li>
    <ul>
243,17,<I write something sn2370292kl@$^&,hahhaha
```

Head is `id,age,note`,`note` is string input by students,can be any character.

In `read.csv("qlist.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",",quote ="\"",na.strings = c(""," "),check.names=TRUE,fill=FALSE,strip.white = FALSE,comment.char = "",allowEscapes = FALSE,stringsAsFactors =FALSE,skipNul = FALSE)`,I think I cannot use `,` as delimeter because of `I am handsome,I am 18.`

Then,which delimeter can be used to prevent delimeter being the part of input?

Plus,I tried G. Grothendieck's answer:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.3                         
year           2019                        
month          03                          
day            11                          
svn rev        76217                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
nickname       Great Truth                 
> Lines <- 'id,age,note
+ 241,18,I am handsome,I am "18".
+ 242,19, <ul>
+ <li>
+ <strong>I like music</strong><br />
+ Talor swift：I kike Talor,I like her concert{smile}.<br />
+ Beyonce:I have 3 albums.</li>
+ <ul>
+ 243,17,<I write something sn2370292kl@$^&,hahhaha'
> L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
> L2 <- lapply(split(L, cumsum(grepl("^\\S", L))), function(x) {
+     x <- gsub('"', '""', x)
+     x[1] <- sub('^(.*?,.*?,)', '\\1"', x[1])
+     x[length(x)] <- paste0(x[length(x)], '"')
+     x
+ })
> DF <- read.csv(text = unname(unlist(L2)))
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
> dim(DF)
[1] 5 3
```

Comment: You have to *quote* stings containing the delimiter. E.g. `read.csv(header=FALSE, text="241,18,\"I am handsome,I am 18.\"")`

Comment: @GKi,csv file has 2000 lines,it's hard to manually edit `read.csv`.

Comment: How about set `|\t` as delimeter when write this csv,then `read.csv(...sep="|\t"...)`,because `|\t` is too complex to input .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to have quotes around multi-line fields.  First read in the file using `readLines`, split it into logical records and put double quotes around the third field.  Then read that with `read.csv`.

*We have assumed that lines that match the grep pattern defined in variable `pat` are the lines that are not continued from the prior lines.  In particular we are assuming that lines that begin with digits, comma, digits and comma are not continued from the prior line.  Revise `pat` appropriately if that assumption does not hold.*

```
# L <- readLines("myfile.csv")
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
# pat <- "^\\S"  # this pattern worked for original input shown in question
pat <- "^\\d+,\\d+,"
L2 <- lapply(split(L, cumsum(grepl(pat, L))), function(x) {
  x <- gsub('"', '""', x)
  x[1] <- sub('^(.*?,.*?,)', '\\1"', x[1])
  x[length(x)] <- paste0(x[length(x)], '"')
  x
})
DF <- read.csv(text = unname(unlist(L2)))
dim(DF)
## [1] 3 3
```

### Note

```
Lines <- 'id,age,note
241,18,I am handsome,I am "18".
242,19, <ul>
    <li>
        <strong>I like music</strong><br />
        Talor swift：I kike Talor,I like her concert{smile}.<br />
        Beyonce:I have 3 albums.</li>
    <ul>
243,17,<I write something sn2370292kl@$^&,hahhaha'
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.I cannot repeat in R 3.5.3.I got 5 obs. of 3 variables,and `Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string`

Comment: Still cannot repeat in R 3.5.3,with R studio 1.1.463

Comment: I update question,add the output when I run your answer,I just copy and paster your answer.

Comment: In the original input shown in the question the continuation lines all began with space and we did state in the answer that that was the assumed form of the input.  To quote the answer:: *We have assumed that lines that begin with space are continued from the prior line.*.  In the revised input this is no longer the case.  If we can assume that continuation lines are those lines that do not begin with digits, a comma, more digits and another comma then replace the grep pattern with one which matches that.  We have defined a revised `pat` in the code to handle that revised assumption.